# How can I install PHP PECL extension "SQLite" on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu, pecl

I tried installing using the PECL command from documentation:

> $ sudo pecl install SQLite [sudo] password for bogdanbiv:  downloading
>   SQLite-1.0.3.tgz ... Starting to download SQLite-1.0.3.tgz (371,189
>   bytes) .......done: 371,189 bytes 50 source files, building running:
>   phpize Cannot find config.m4. Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize'
>   in the top level source directory of the module

So I tried to download the package manually:

> $ sudo pecl download SQLite 
>   File /home/$USER/Downloads/SQLite-1.0.3.tgz downloaded

These were the first files listed in the archive:

> $ tar -tzf SQLite-1.0.3.tgz
>
> > package.xml
> >     SQLite-1.0.3/config.m4 ### config.m4 is in the archive, why isn't it found?
> >     SQLite-1.0.3/sqlite.c
> >     SQLite-1.0.3/sqlite.dsp
> >     SQLite-.0.3/php_sqlite.h
> >     ...

So I unpacked the archive to folder /usr/share/php/SQLite-1.0.3.

> /usr/share/php/SQLite-1.0.3$ sudo phpize
>   Configuring for:
>   PHP Api Version: 20121113 
>   Zend Module Api No: 20121212 
>   Zend Extension Api No: 220121212

After running phpize I would expect PHP to load the SQLite extention, but the only place it appears in the phpinfo page is in the Module Authors (credits). Tried restarting Ubuntu, but even after a restart PHP does not find SQLite.

I am using PECL version only because I saw it as the recomended way to install the PHP SQLite extension. I also tried earlier to install SQLite from Ubuntu packages, also unsuccessful, I will ask that in a separate question.

Disclaimer: I read that using SQLite with sqlite_open is supposed to be deprecated, I just need it to get past an example without which I am blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using PECL version only because I saw it as the recomended way to
>   install the PHP SQLite extension.

You should not be using the PECL version of this extension, as sqlite support is now part of PHP.

For saucy, install the `php5-sqlite` package.

Installing the `sqlite` package directly will only install the *client* and not any integrations or libraries.

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 sqlite is no longer part of PHP and in only available through PECL.